# How do i resolve "Dynamic param x could not be resolved, Treating it as static param"

Tags: javascript, bdd, getgauge

Im trying to resolve my code conflicts in gauge. So far i've run into a few problems but this one has had me stuck. "Dynamic param x could not be resolved, Treating it as static param"

i'm trying to run the following scenario in gauge...

```
# Invalid payload structures

setup steps
*  Given a service

## Invalid structures 
    | template                                   | failMessage                         |
    |--------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------|
    | triage:invalidStructure_endUserIds         | "endUserId" is required             |

*  Given I prepare a JSON request for "<template>"
*  When I "post" the request
*  Then I expect the response code "400"
*  And I expect the response parameters
    | Field                   | Value               |
    |-------------------------|---------------------|
    | errorCode               | 1005                |
    | errorMessage            | Invalid user input  |
    | validationFailures      | <failMessage>       |
```

expectation:

1> i would expect the data table to execute at a scenario level. This was not straight forward and i had to add "allow_scenario_datatable=true" in gauge properties.

2> gauge fails to resolve  dynamically and i see the following error. "Dynamic param  could not be resolved, Treating it as static param"

Any help or direction would ease my pain

Comment: table in scenario is an experimental feature, hence the need for `allow_scenario_datatable=true`. Can you share the your spec file in code blocks, that'll help identify the possible cause. Over here I see it being formatted as html.

Comment: Hi @Srikanth i've updated the description with the actual code block for clarity on what i'm trying to achieve here

Comment: This should be addressed as part of https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues/1330.